# Can not access GUIText in instantiated prefab

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a prefab with the following component structure:

- Block

  - `Quad`
  - `RawImage`
  - `GUIText`

---

When I instantiate it and try to access the `GUIText`, I get the output of 'null'.

Here is the code, I am using to access the `GUIText`:

```
public GameObject Block;

GameObject obj = Instantiate(Block, position, orientation) as GameObject;
GUIText myText = obj.GetComponent<GUIText>();
print(myText);
```

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? It *may* be relevant. It has been pointed out that `GUIText` is legacy; regardless, it should still work as your intending to use it.

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.3 on Windows 10

Comment: @Gnemlock <Facepalm> You were right, I was trying to access it as GUIText when it was a simple Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually *at least* two problems:

1. Your trying to access the *text*, but your only referencing the *container*.
2. There still does not appear to be a `GUIText` component attached to your game object.

---

First and foremost, `GUIText` is a *class* that contains the text as one of the variables. If you want to access the *text*, itself, you need to use `GUIText.text`.

That said, that does not account for `GUIText` outputting a `string` value of `null`. Unfortunetly, the only thing that really does is if `GetComponent<GUIText>` initially returns a `null` reference. It is hard to say *why* this is the case, but ultimately, it does not sound like there actually *is* a `GUIText` directly attached to the game object.

---

It is difficult to assess the *exact* cause as of this point, but there are a few possible causes and solutions.

- Perhaps you mean to say that `Block` contains a *child* that contains a `GUIText`? We need to use `GetComponentInChildren(type)`, if that is the case.

  - Note that this works off the assumption that there is *still* only one `GUIText` in the entire hierarchy of `Block`. If this is not the case, you will have to further ensure you have the correct reference.
  - You will also note that this method does not use a generic (`<T>`). Instead, you would write it as `GetComponentInChildren(type of(GUIText))`.
- Perhaps, through human error, your actually referencing an object  or instance that does not *have* a `GUIText` component. If you want to account for the possibility, which is considered a good practice, you have two options:

  1. Place any code accessing `myText` inside an `if` statement that checks that `myText != null`. Remember, *trying to retrieve a component that does not exist will not cause errors, but further access will*. You can have an `else` statement follow, if you want somewhere to put debug output if the check fails.
  2. If you *must* have a `GUIText` object directly on that object, you can mark use the `[RequireComponent]` attribute on a script that is attached to that object. Simple include `[RequireComponeny(type of(GUIText))]` directly above the main class, and if your object does not have one, the class will automatically create one. If you do not have a script attached to the object that is *unique* to the object (or rather, unique to game objects that should contain a `GUIText` component), create one just for this purpose.
- Failing all this, it might be worth setting up the `GUIText` as a pre-setup `public` reference on a local script. This script would be attached to your prefab object, ideally with all required references set up, internally. You would than grab a reference to the script using `GetComponent<T>`, as you are, now. The core difference is that you would only have to do it *once* to have the access you require, assuming you require reference to the other components. This also acts as a way around issues that may be isolated to the exact way you have the `GUIText` set up.

---

Do *not* use `GameObject.Find` to clarify your reference to the initial game object, as suggested by an alternate answer.

- `GameObject.Find` can be *slow*. It is not ideal, especially if you frequently run this code.
- `GameObjevt.Find` returns the *first* game object that is found to match. There is no guarantee *which* instance this will be, if you have multiple, so it can be especially unreliable.